# Hide Parent's sbling ui-view quadrant when in a child state

Tags: angular-ui, angular-ui-bootstrap, angular-ui-router

When I go to a child state, I want to hide a ui-view component of a quadrant ui-view in root state. How can achieve this.

```
##index.html

<div ui-view="a">
</div>
<div ui-view="b">
</div>
<div ui-view="c">
</div>

##b.html

<div ui-view>
</div>

##config

$stateProvider.state('start', {
         'views': {
                   'a': {
                        templateUrl: ...
                        },
                   'b': {
                         templateUrl: 'b.html'
                        },
                   'c': {
                         templateUrl: ...
                        }
                  },
           controller: 'indexController
         }).state('start.all', {
                   templateUrl: 'd.html',
                   controller:  'allController'
                 });
```

So when I reach start.all, I would like that  the ui-view tagged c vanishes. How can I accomplish this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is [an example](http://plnkr.co/edit/6J1LT0wV5DfgLNFUJnSE?p=preview) demonstrating approach discussed below. The native way of `ui-router`, I'd say, is to manage all the views from current (active) state. We can do it with :

- View Names - [Relative vs. Absolute Names](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Multiple-Named-Views#view-names---relative-vs-absolute-names)

> ... Behind the scenes, every view gets assigned an absolute name that follows a scheme of **`viewname@statename`**, where viewname is the name used in the view directive and state name is the state's absolute name, e.g. *contact.item*

In our case, the full name of the view 'c' would be `c@`, i.e. `c` as view name, `@` as delimiter and empty string representing the root *(a bit weird but in fact logical)*.

Having that we can change the start.all definition like this:

```
.state('start.all', {
    url : '/all',
    'views': {
      '': {
        template: '<span>this is start ALL</span>',
      },
      'c@': {
        template: '<span></span>',
      },
    },
  })
```

And we will change the content of the `c` view in the root. And that should be the most native way with `ui-router`. It does not effectively remove it, but we can replace it with some empty stuff.

Also, into your example above, I placed controller called `bController` as contra example to the `indexController`:

```
.state('start', {
    url : '/start',
    'views': {
      'a': {
        template: ...
      },
      'b': {
        template: ...
        // HERE a new controller bController
        controller: 'bController', 
      },
      'c': {
        template: ...
      }
    },
    // the orginal contoller
    controller: 'indexController',
  })
```

and also defined them this way:

```
.controller('indexController', function($scope, $state, $stateParams) {
  console.log('indexConroller was invoked');
})
.controller('bController', function($scope, $state, $stateParams) {
  console.log('bConroller was invoked');
})
```

Why? to show you, that `indexController` will never be invoked. Contollers belongs to templates/views not to state...

Check all that together [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/6J1LT0wV5DfgLNFUJnSE?p=preview)

Comment: Thanks for helping with one very relevant example of viewname@statename. this seems to work very well. Good working example

Comment: +1 but I think this is a bit of a hack. Not shown on the answer here (but in the Plunker) is the tacking on of the `<ui-view />` element onto the 'b' view template. That is pretty arbitrary and confusing. Technically more correct than my answer, but surely you don't override views like this in real applications?

Comment: @david004, just to your comment *... is the tacking on of the `<ui-view />` element onto the 'b' view template...* My plunker is doing the same as was in a question. I did followed that 100%. I just inlined above **`templateUrl: 'b.html'`** and its **`<div ui-view></div>`** into one line: template: `'<div>this is B <ui-view /></div>'`. These are the same...;)

Answer (score 0):

You could do it in a few ways. One way would be to have an abstract state containing views `a` and `b`. That abstract state then has two concrete child states: `start`, which adds view `c`, and `all`, which adds view `d`.

Another option is to just use the `ng-show` directive on the c view's root element bound to some scope variable. I would go with the first option.

Notably this does not answer the question because `all` is no longer a child of `start`. If there is a real need for `all` to inherit from `start` (there appears to be no need at present) you can just make `start` abstract and create a `start.main` and `start.all`.

Though Radim's solution is very clever and much appreciated, I think this is much more readable and intuitive than overriding a parent view with an empty template.

```
<body>
    <div ng-app="myApp">
        <a ui-sref="start.main">start</a> | <a ui-sref="start.all">all</a>
        <hr />
        <div class="rootView" ui-view="a"></div>
        <div class="rootView" ui-view="b"></div>
        <div class="rootView" ui-view=""></div>
    </div>
<script>

    var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['ui.router']);

    myApp.config(function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

        $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/start/main');

        $stateProvider

        // Content common to all views
        .state('shell', {
            abstract: true,
            views: {
                "a": { template: '<div>View a here.</div>' },
                "b": { template: '<div>View b here.</div>' },
                "": { template: '<div ui-view></div>' }
                }
        })
        // Content common to all 'start' views (currently nothing)
        .state('start', {
                parent: 'shell',
                url: '/start',
                abstract: true,
                template: '<div ui-view></div>'
        })
        .state('start.main', {
                url: '/main',
                template: '<div>View c is here</div>'
        })
        .state('start.all', {
                url: '/all',
                template: '<div>View d is here</div>'
        });
});

</script>
</body>
```

Comment: Second option, Didn't like the ng-show idea. 
First Option, What you said is probably a cleaner structuring of ui-views to solve my need, but I like Radim Köhler's method. Indicates that one can do things from even deep within hierarchy.